# Datastax Object Mapping API Performances

Tags: java, performance, cassandra, datastax

I am using the Datastax Driver (Java) with Cassandra 2.1, and I was wondering if there are benefits, in terms of performance, using the Accessor-annotated interfaces rather than Prepared Statements.

Basically, I wonder what is the best method between:

**Method 1 :**

```
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE name = ?");
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement.bind("someone"));

User user = userMapper.map(resultSet).one();
```

AND

**Method 2 :**

```
@Accessor
public interface UserAccessor {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name = :name")
    User getUser(@Param("userName") String name);
}

...

MappingManager manager = new MappingManager (getSession());
User user = new User ();
UserAccessor userAccessor = manager.createAccessor(UserAccessor.class);
User user = userAccessor.getUser("someone");
```

Moreover, should I use this mapper if I want performances, or simple Bound Statements with POJO are better ?

**Example from [Datastax Documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientAddSession_t.html)**

```
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE name = ?");
BoundStatement bind= statement.bind("someone");

ResultSet results = session.execute(bind);
for (Row row : results) {
    User user = new User (row.getString("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I cannot find a good reference to link to, but afaik `@Accessor` queries are prepared too.
2. The choice you are making depends mostly on the approach you'll feel more comfortable with. Depending on your app, even if there might be some overhead in using the mapper, it might not be significant.